# Axios isn't writing status 401 on 401 error response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to catch 401 error in the error callback of axios (I just want to detect that it's a 401 error) , but it doesn't has any attribute that indicate about 401 .

i.e -

```
test401() {
    var self = this;
    axios.post('https://mail.google.com/sync/u/0/i/fd?hl=en&c=12')
    .catch( (error) => {
        self.setState({data: error.status || "No Status" });
      console.log("catch ", error); // No any status here
    });
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/gbc2sp3j/2/) if you want to check it

How could I know in axios that I got 401 error response ?

Comment: It says "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mail.google.com/sync/u/0/i/fd?hl=en&c=12' from origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." — So you can't access the status of the reqest from JavaScript.

Comment: It should be `error.response.status`

Comment: @Quentin , oh really ? even if I can see the 401 in the  console ?

Comment: "oh really ?" – Yes, the duplicate explains that

Comment: "even if I can see the 401 in the console ?" — Yes, the duplicate explains why